# Strategy or Factor pattern for sorting logic

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am design a class diagram and i got confused how to use the sorting logic.

Requirement : 
Sorting logic can be

1. sort by field1
2. sort by field2
3. sort by field1+field2+field3
   and can be many more.
   ![enter image description here][1]

Solution
I m thinking to create class for all possible logic and a interface above them.

Which pattern should i use strategy or factory.

Please help me on this

Comment: Is database involved and you just want to compose ORDER BY, or do you sort data yourself?

Comment: Sounds a lot like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139073/why-not-factory-pattern-for-sorting/10146454). Factory is a logical complement to Strategy pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Strategy pattern or visitor pattern is best suited for this.
this requirement is very common and so i suggest anyone having good knowledge of class diagram can upload it here

Comment: Thanx , 
can you elaborate on this

Answer (score 1):

The strategy pattern is best here and although [it's Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is a good reference, it's not a good beginner piece.

Put simply (ignoring interfaces, type checking etc), you make separate classes for each potential sorting algorithm, then pass an instance of one of the sorting classes to your object's constructor so it can be used. Your main class then delegates the sorting action to whatever sorter got passed in, something like this:

```
class mainthing {

    public function __construct($sorter) {
        $this->sorter = $sorter;
    }

    public function sort($stufftosort) {
        return $this->sorter->sort($stufftosort);
    }

}

class sorter {
    public function sort($stufftosort) {
        // sorting code here
    }

}

class differentsorter {
    public function sort($stufftosort) {
        // different sorting code here
    }

}

$thing = new mainthing(new sorter());
$thing->sort($somestuff);
$otherthing = new mainthing(new differentsorter());
$otherthing->sort($somestuff);
```

The idea is that instead of being tied into a strict inheritance hierarchy, you can mix and match different behaviours. Maybe you have other stuff that should vary about those classes, not just the sorting - just do the same thing by passing into the constructor an object that can provide that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider here, the sorting algorithm itself, and the comparison function. You seem to be after a comparison function, which is a kind of strategy that just knows how to compare two items in a list, which the sorting algorithm will use to sort a list.

So, from a conceptual perspective, you'd have a `Comparator` interface with a method `compare(a, b)` that returns the comparison result between its parameters. This interface is simple enough that a callback function suffices in most cases. Take a look at the [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function for an example.